# setErrorByName() not highlighting multi-select fields

Tags: 8, forms

I have the following HTML code, generated by drupal

```
<div class="multiselect-selected">
<select multiple="multiple" name="field_test_ins[]" data-drupal-selector="edit-field-test-ins" aria-describedby="edit-field-test-ins--description" id="edit-field-test-ins" size="12" class="multiselect-selected form-multiselect">
</div>
```

In custom **test_validate()**, I tried below approaches for multi-select field highlighting in validation function.

```
function test_validate(&$form, &$form_state) {

//Tried below ways:

//Case 1:
    $form_state->setErrorByName('field_test_ins', t("ERROR_MESSAGE-1"));

//Case 1:
    $form_state->setErrorByName('field_test_ins][', t("ERROR_MESSAGE-1"));

//Case 3:
    $form_state->setErrorByName('field_test_ins]', t("ERROR_MESSAGE-1"));

}
```

When I submit the form, the error message appears at the top of the form, but the multi-select field is not highlighted.

I tried all the above approaches, but no luck.

Can anybody suggest how to highlight this multi-select field?

Comment: Is this form created by code *Form APi* or you altering drupal form such as *Edit node Form*, i tested it with created form by code for example `$form['select_user'] = [
      '#type'        => 'select',
      '#title'       => t('Select a user'),...`   so  `$form_state->setErrorByName('select_user', t("ERROR_MESSAGE-1"));`  work just fine with highlight .

Comment: I am altering for EDIT node form. In one of my content types multi-select field is there, so I'm adding custom validation for that field.

Comment: I tested it it works also with `$form_state->setErrorByName('field_test_ins', t("ERROR_MESSAGE-1"));` , which admin theme you work with ?

Comment: I'm using radix theme. can you try one thing, create one multiselect field in one of the content type and add the custom validation for that field and check highlighting is working or not.

Comment: you use Radix as admin  theme ?

Comment: Yes you are right, it doesn't work with radix, i have dig into it a little bit, but with no success, you can post an issue to radix theme here https://www.drupal.org/node/add/project-issue/radix

Comment: I have tested it even with custom form created using Form api, it doesn't work either, not even with multi-select but with all kind of inputs

Comment: Hey @berramou,Thanks for sharing your thoughts, In radix I tried with other input types like plain text field and text long. For these fields validation is working with highlight.